# ASP.Net URL Rewriter

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

We're using URLRewriter (http://urlrewriter.net), and would like to rewrite queries like this:

domain.com/find/red-boots

to this:
domain.com/search.aspx?k=red+boots

The sample code to go into the web.config is this (I'm a bit unfamiliar with this syntax)

`<if url="/tags/(.+)" rewrite="/tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1" />`

How can I code this line in the web.config to get it to rewrite the way we need?  Also, if you have any good advice on how to brush up on the rewriter syntax, that would be great too.

Comment: I think you've missed the link...

Comment: do you need to support red-red-red-blue-boots as well, cause it gets really tricky with the regexes

Comment: yes, it could be any number of words separated by hyphen...I made the code readable above as well.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong @Sam and @alchemical, but it looks like anything after the /find/ path should be included in the `k=` query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rewriter syntax" you are asking about is called regular expressions.  There are many great tools out there, just search Google for "regex help".

However if you would like to use a syntax that has a little more history behind it, so you can get more detailed help.  Please check out the [Managed Fusion Url Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com), which uses the Apache mod_rewrite syntax, which has been the standard for more years than I can cound.  Here is how you would complete your question in mod_rewrite syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^/find/(.*)       /search.aspx?k=$1      [NC,L]
```

The first part after the `RewriteRule` is the input that tries to get matched against the URL Requested by the browser.  The second part is the transformation, that happens against the matched rule.  The transformation turns it into something your application can understand.  The last part in the brackets are control tags, in this case I am telling the `RewriteRule` to not worry about the case of the characters which is indicated by `NC` and that if matched it should treat this as the last processed rule which is indicated by `L`

Comment: I downloaded it, read the readme, referenced it, edited web.config, but can't get it to do anything...any advice?  Also couldn't locate any documentation for this...

Comment: This isn't really the right support forum for this.  Please post the question over on the site, and I will be able to help you more.